# How to delete a row from treeview by number of this row?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I want to delete a row from treeview table and insert into place of deleted row a new row.
I know there is a method like:

```
r = tree.get_children()
for item in r:
    tree.delete(item)
```

But this method deletes all rows from a table. Also there is another method, which requires the item to be selected:

```
def remove_item():
    selected_items = tree.selection()
    for selected_item in selected_items:
        tree.delete(selected_item)
```

Is there a method which can delete row by number of this row?

For example, i have 5 rows in the table and want to delete the third row:

```
selected_items = tree.???(3)
for selected_item in selected_items:
    tree.delete(selected_item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the row ID of the third row as below:

```
selected_item = tree.get_children()[2]  # index starts from 0
```

Then delete it as below:

```
tree.delete(selected_item)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me because I wanted to show only 100 items, and when a new item is added to the table, the first item should be deleted automatically.